# prevent webview lock on ios phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, webview

I have a page with an input box at the bottom. When I click on the input box the keyboard opens and shift the webview up.

Is there any way to be able to scroll on the webview instead of fixing on the input box?